# Webrtc Android libjingle I420Frame constructor are now private

Tags: java, android, webrtc, libjingle

I based my previous code on this:

https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc/stable/talk/+/fbb1efa61417540336cf52976d4ff4394bfa795b/examples/android/src/org/appspot/apprtc

But I decide to update my lib, I build `libjingle_peerconnection.jar` and `libjingle_peerconnection_so.so` based on this:

https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc/+/master/webrtc/examples/androidapp/README

But now in my VideoStreamView, I've got some problem in `queueFrame()` because there is no longer a `copyFrom()` on I420Frame in the new version and even in the `takeFrame()` I am unable to create new I420Frame because constructors are now private.